# How do I allow Chrome to use my microphone programmatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, ruby-mocha

I am currently trying to run some tests made with webdriverjs and chromedriver but they need microphone permissions.

This is the popup that shows up:

[image: popup image]

I have tried:

```
    chromedriver.start(['--disable-popup-blocking']);
    driver = new Webdriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(Webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
    .build();
```

but it didn't work.

I also tried

```
    driver.wait(Until.alertIsPresent(), config.TIMEOUT, 'Alert did not show up');
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

it did not work either! I guess that this is not an ordinary alert.

Useful links:

[Chrome startup arguments list](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)

[Chrome options for java and ruby](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities)

[Chromedriver github](https://github.com/giggio/node-chromedriver)

**How do I give them permissions programmatically?**

**Is there any flag or some other way around this?**

Comment: This is security thing and most probably Google Chrome will not allow to circumvent it. On `https:` pages you have to give permission only once.

Comment: pfffff, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev, as a matter of fact, Chrome has disabled accessing userMedia, microphone, geoLocation, and most APIs on non-SSL domain.  `localhost` is considered as a secure domain though (for development purposes).

Comment: Well it should stop asking for mic permissions then... xD

Comment: Check site's setting (lock icon on left of address bar) [screenshot](http://image.prntscr.com/image/5f34b364405945baa1bbe4e7ab9874eb.png)

Comment: It asks for permission on each request on `http:` pages and once per domain on `https:`pages. If user click `Block` then microphone will be blocked for this domain. This is default behavior.

Comment: `--use-fake-device-for-media-stream` did not work either

Comment: Do not forget that chrome is launched as "brand new". No settings, extensions etc.

Comment: Adam even if i set "Always allow" it will only set it 1 time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fresh profile is loaded each time you run selenium, hence changes you make to the preferences and website permissions are not preserved between sessions. To amend this we need to tell selenium which profile to load.

Step 1. Find your Chrome preferences file: [www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Configuration](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Google_Chrome#Configuration)

Step 2. Copy the folder `Default` somewhere. I will assume it is copied to `/some/path/allow-mic/Default`.

Alternative Step 3 (this is easier):
Before copying `Default` visit `localhost:1337` with Chrome and set mic to always allow.

Step 3. Edit `allow-mic/Default/Preferences`, find the tags `"profile"`, `"content_settings"` and `"exceptions"` within each other and add

```
"media_stream_mic":{"http://localhost:1337,*":
                                          {"last_used":1470931206,
                                           "setting":1} },
```

to `"exceptions"`. You should end up with something like:

```
...
"profile":{
     ...
     "content_settings": {
         ...
         "exceptions": {
             ...
             "media_stream_mic":{"http://localhost:1337,*":
                                      {"last_used":1470931206,
                                       "setting":1} },
             ...
         },
    },
},
...
```

Step 4:
Configure `selenium` to use the edited preferences:

```
var chromedriver = require('chromedriver');
var Webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var opts = new chrome.Options();                   
opts.addArguments("user-data-dir=/some/path/allow-camera");

var driver = new chrome.Driver(opts);
```

You can check that the correct set of preferences (Profile path) are in use by opening `chrome://version/`.

Comment: Looks nice, i will have a try with this later. I have to find ChromeOptions inside webdriverjs though.

Comment: I was not able to use this tip. I setted the path to a folder that had a Preferences file that had the following settings:

"media_stream_mic":{"http://localhost:1337,*":{"last_used":1473864155.757848,"setting":1},"http://localhost:1338,*":{"last_used":1470767319.186194,"setting":1},...}

When i run selenium, it still asks for mic permissions.

Comment: Could you try to add "http://...,*" to your urls, so that they match the urls in the answer? Have you tried using the alternative Step 3? Have you checked chrome://version to confirm that you are using the correct set of preferences?

Answer (score 14):

A little late but pasting how to do this here for others looking for the same.

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'), By = webdriver.By, until = webdriver.until,Builder= webdriver.Builder;

var chrome = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome');

var chromeOptions = new chrome.Options()
.addArguments('allow-file-access-from-files')
.addArguments('use-fake-device-for-media-stream')
.addArguments('use-fake-ui-for-media-stream');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
.forBrowser('chrome')
.setChromeOptions(chromeOptions);

driver = driver.build();
```

Comment: Thanks - just `'use-fake-ui-for-media-stream'` was enough to fix my mic permission problem.

Comment: Awesome! Also worked in Java Selenium:

```ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("use-fake-device-for-media-stream");
options.addArguments("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);```

Answer (score 5):

For those using Python, this worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can whitelist a url for audio-capture by providing chromedriver with the *hardware.audio_capture_allowed_urls* preference.

```
...
chrome_options = Options()
prefs = {"hardware.audio_capture_allowed_urls" : ["example.org"]}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similarly, for use in `Splinter`

```
    from splinter import Browser
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 
    chrome_options = Options() 
    chrome_options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream") 
    Browser('chrome', ** {'executable_path':'chromedriver'},options=chrome_options)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the microphone,

```
chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_experimental_option('prefs',{'profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic':1})


driver = webdriver.Chrome(path,chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Add some description to your code, it will help understand better.