# Robot framework, Open Browser with command line flag to save browser log

Tags: maven, google-chrome, selenium, testing, robotframework

I'm trying to save browser (chrome) log messages (React logs, js errors etc.) into a file in a *robot framework* test run. Apparently this is more difficult than it should be, as I couldn't find convenient API in robot framework to achieve this.

I figured out chrome could be started with `--enable-logging --v=1` flag to direct log messages into a file. But how could I pass this flag via `Open Browser` keyword in robot framework? To be more precise, I'm actually using `robotframework-maven-plugin` to run the tests with *headless* browser on the remote server.

This is how test is currently started on the remote server from jenkins via execute remote shell task

```
rm -rf tests
git clone git@*****/tests.git && cd tests
Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x24 &
export DISPLAY=:99
mvn -DforceOpenJpaExecution=true -Dbrowser=chrome -Dserver=***** -DchromeDriverPath=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver clean verify
```

Here is the `pom.xml` of the test project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>*****</groupId>
    <artifactId>tests</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>tests</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.markusbernhardt</groupId>
            <artifactId>robotframework-selenium2library-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>verify</defaultGoal>        

        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>setPropertyChromeDriver</id>
                    <phase>integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <properties>
                            <property>
                              <name>webdriver.chrome.driver</name>
                              <value>${chromeDriverPath}</value>
                            </property>
                        </properties>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>robotframework-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${robotframework-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>robotTest</id>  
                <phase>integration-test</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And here is the excerpt from `resource.robot`

```
    Open the web application
        Open Browser    %{server}/App    %{browser}
        Maximize Browser Window
        Wait Until Page Contains        Login
```

Now, how could I pass the `--enable-logging --v=1` to chrome driver, or is there more convenient way to dumb browser log to a file or test results?

I found this piece of code to set the flags, but I have no idea how to apply it in keyword based resource in my case

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# set some options
# for example:
# options.add_argument('--disable-logging')
driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())
```

Answer (score 1):

When you need to pass options to webdriver with Selenium2Library you should use the keyword `Create Webdriver` (and later `Go To` url).

Answer (score 0):

In a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389550/how-to-handle-web-based-alert-or-pop-ups-in-robot-framework/43424356#43424356) I provided an answer that should apply here as well

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Selenium2Library
*** Test Cases ***

Log Chrome Console
      ${c_opts} =  Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].ChromeOptions()    sys, selenium.webdriver
      Call Method     ${c_opts}   add_argument             enable-logging 
      Call Method     ${c_opts}   add_argument             v\=1
      Create Webdriver    Chrome    crm_alias    chrome_options=${c_opts}
      Go To    http://www.url.com
      [Teardown]  Close All Browsers
```

This adds the arguments to the command line of Chrome.